# can't reopen featherlight div after closing it

Tags: featherlight.js

I've started using FeatherLight and have a small problem:
I have a simple div. Here is its code:

```
<div id="AddNewItemToMenu" style="display:none;">....</div>
```

Basically i can open the lightbox and it is shown perfectly and everything is ok - UNTIL i manually force a close of the lightbox popup via Javascript.
After closing it once? - when i try to reload it again, i get an empty lightbox (maybe the close operation erased the div's content).

For the close command i use:

```
$.featherlight.close();
```

and for the opening command (opening of the featherlight lightbox) i use the following command:

```
$.featherlight($('#AddNewItemToMenu'), { 'persist' : true });
```

Any ideas why that happens?.
Maybe there is another methood of hiding instead of closing? (something that won't vanish my div?).

Thank you!.

Updated:
I've attached an example file. Uploaded to some temp site. here is the link: https://ufile.io/wxipg
When opening index.html => click on the "Open Featherlight" and then close the popup and then click on the "Open Featherlight" again, and you'll see empty div.

Comment: A minimal working example would help

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded an example to here: https://ufile.io/wxipg   => Also updated main topic with instructions on what to do to see the problem

Comment: Thanks. Next time, best use tools like jsfiddle/codepen/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use featherlight's binding (e.g. `$('#open-fl').featherlight(...)`), or else use the result of `$.featherlight` to re-open it, e.g.:

```
var fl = $.featherlight(...); // Opens dialog a first time
fl.close(); // Closing it via JS
fl.open(); // Opening again
```

Comment: i've just replied on a topic you answered on at 2015. took me 2 days to come up with the solution (yours, from 2015). wish the documentation on the featherlight website was clearer :( many thanks my friend

Comment: Please consider making a PR to improve the doc :-)

Comment: whatever helps you. I see that you are helping everyone else, and might be the owner. many thanks and you've done a great job with this one.